# Changing color of a discord role

Tags: python, discord.py

Everything is set up right, the bot is in the discord, connected, etc.
This code:

```
import discord
import random

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    color2 = "%06x" % random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF)
    print(color2)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!randomcolor'):
        server = client.get_guild('')
        role = "Rainbow tester"
        color = "%06x" % random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF)
        await role.edit(server=server, role=role, colour=color)
        await message.channel.send('Trying that...')

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Gives this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 22, in on_message
    await role.edit(server=server, role=role, colour=color)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'edit'
```

If anyone can find where I went wrong or any errors I've made, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `discord.Color.random()` function for that as it looks like the problem occurs in your `color`-line.

**Re-write your code to the following:**

```py
from discord.utils import get

    if message.content.startswith('!randomcolor'):
        guild = client.get_guild(GuildID)
        role = get(guild.roles, name="Rainbow tester") # Get the role
        color = discord.Color.random() # Choose a random color
        await role.edit(server=guild, role=role, colour=color)
        await message.channel.send('Trying that...')
```

**What did we do?**

- Imported `from discord.utils import get`
- Changed the way we get the role: (`get(guild.roles, name="Rainbow tester")` or `role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name='Rainbow tester'`)
- Used the `discord.Color.random()` function to choose a random color

Comment: I have made your changes, but I'm now getting the error
"  File "main.py", line 22, in on_message
    await role.edit(server=server, role=role, colour=color)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'edit'"

Comment: The error is self-explanatory, then the role does not exist `(None)`. I would possibly even work with the ID of the role and not with the name. Make sure the bot is above the role so it can be edited.

Comment: Thanks, what a doo-dah mistake I made, I incorrectly entered the role name lmao, thanks for your time and patience!

Comment: A little tip from my side: Use the ID, so instead of `name='RoleName'` just use `id=RoleID` and you can change the name of the role as often as you want, errors can't happen there anymore. Have fun coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name='Rainbow tester')
```